# pathogen#infect not updating the runtimepath

Tags: vim

I have started working with pathogen.vim with gvim on Windows, following Tim Pope's setup guide at his github repository [here.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

However, I'm running into the problem that pathogen#infect() does not seem to be modifying the runtimepath (as seen by running `:echo &runtimepath` in gvim).

The simple test case _vimrc that I came up with is as follows. Please note that pathogen gets loaded just fine.

```
"Set a base directory.
let $BASE_DIR='H:\development\github\vimrc'

"Source pathogen since it's not in the normal autoload directory.
source $BASE_DIR\autoload\pathogen.vim

"Start up pathogen
call pathogen#infect()
"call pathogen#infect('$BASE_DIR\functions')
```

Neither running `pathogen#infect()` without an argument (which should add the bundles directory under the vimfiles directory) nor specifying a directory to contain files works.

Substituting the `pathogen#infect()` call with `pathogen#runtime_prepend_subdirectories('$BASE_DIR\functions')`, which is what `pathogen#infect()` does fails to change the runtimepath as well.

Any ideas that I've missed? Any more information that would be helpful?

My repository with the non-trivial example is [here.](https://github.com/trprice/vimrc)

***EDIT***

In addition to creating directories under the directory I infected, as mentioned by qqx, I renamed those directories to plugin and colors which Vim will automatically load vim files from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathogen#infect()` doesn't add the `bundle` directory or the directory named in the argument to `&runtimepath`, only subdirectories of that directory. In your github repository, the vimrc file uses the `functions` directory as the argument, but that directory only has files in it no subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks, I see that if I create a directory under the functions directory, it shows up in the runtimepath.